# Как создать динамически подгружаемый многоуровневый список на чистом JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, list, список

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: примерный макет]

Подскажите пожалуйста алгоритм написания программы для данного списка.
Изначально на макете две кнопки "КАТАЛОГ" и "ИЗБРАННОЕ". При нажатии на "каталог" и далее по уровням вложенности, из каждого пункта списка, должны создаваться новые списки. Их я получаю по API из JSON формата, с этим проблем нет. Страница должна работать без перезагрузок. Код буду писать сам, пожалуйста только алгоритм, заранее благодарен.

Comment: А могете показать пример полученного JSON ? Реализация может быть разной в зависимости от его структуры... И кстати, для какой цели нужно добавлять их именно динамически? Нельзя уж сразу всё вставить, но в виде display: none? Или со временем прилетают новые данные?

Comment: при клике на пункт списка должен подгружаться новый список, код должен быть поддерживаемым, потому что возможно добавление новых данных в исходный JSON. делаю ТЗ.

Comment: https://json.medrating.org/users/

Comment: создаю в html список, а как дальше для каждого пункта сделать новый список не пойму

Answer (score 1):

вариант 1. Использовать `onClick` -> `[].forEach((x) => {if(x.parent ==ourParent){}}`, а после ловить, что менюшка под наведением.

вариант 2. Использовать готовые выпадающие списки. Например, MUI. Там надо лишь передавать Nodes, но такие списки, чаще всего, реакт.

вариант 3.Использовать `clicked` и `hover` в css, изменяя видимость div с дочерними пунктами менюшки

Comment: делегирование событий как оформить понял, хочу сделать без копипаста, чтобы перебирать элементы списка, потом другим циклом делать новый соответствующий выбранному элемент. Что-то вроде цикл в цикле, я пока это так вижу, может не туда копаю.. готовые списки-не вариант и надо на чистом JS. только через css сделать нельзя тоже, элементы должны не быть загружены сразу и просто скрыты, а подгружаться по клику. такое тз

Comment: @ImmortaLKSG используйте перебор. Нужны поля: id, title, isShow, children или parent id
дальше идем перебором: array.map или array.foreach, где вызываем наши объекты, а для тех, что показываем, ставим isShow=true. Таким образом нужен цикл для проверки isShow рекурсивно(если используем children, что предпочтительно) и для поиска по массиву. Возможно, не понятно объяснил. Могу приложить пример кода

Comment: я бы не отказался от примера..)

Comment: @ImmortaLKSG [пример](http://www.realcoding.net/articles/mnogourovnevoe-vypadayushchee-javascript-menyu.html) 
Не мой пример, но вполне показывающий все, что нужно. На его основе можно свой. А вообще, удивительно, что нельзя использовать не нативный js...

Comment: максимально удивительно, спасибо за пример, попробую реализовать